# My department asks to pay back to them the compensation I have received for being a member in a grant proposal assessment committee

Tags: funding, salary, netherlands

Basically, it is as the title says.

I have received an invitation to be a member of a grant proposal committee. They have offered a compensation for each working day (which includes interview sessions). Now, my department asks me to

1. either give them back the entire compensation in a special account, or
2. register vacation days for the days I have worked for this committee.

I was shocked because I never heard about that, the funding institution never mentioned anything like this, and when I asked my "manager" about that in the past, they did not mention anything about this.

The "rationale" (which I find very unconvincing) is that they already pay me so if I do something "Extracurricular" I should register it as vacations, or pay back whatever I have received.

Is this standard practice? Can I avoid it somehow?

Edit: this is The Netherlands and this task is *[not](https://www.utwente.nl/en/service-portal/employment-personal-development/terms-of-employment/ancillary-activities-nevenwerkzaamheden#:%7E:text=The%20definition%20of%20ancillary%20activities,your%20job%20at%20the%20University.)* considered as ancillary activity and so that Collective Labor Agreement about reimbursing the compensation does not apply.

Comment: Why do you expect to be paid twice for 1 days work? Either you are paid by the Grant Committee for that day or your Dept.  This would be the norm in commercial employment, thats if you weren't disciplined or fired for taking a 2nd job without the 1st employers permission.

Comment: @Secretsquirrel It is a 5 days job.

Comment: Is the funding body also in the Netherlands?

Comment: Are they asking to give the money back to the proposal committee or to your department itself?

Comment: @TimRias Yes, in the Netherlands

Comment: @Bergi, my department asks me to give them the compensation I have received from the funding institution.

Comment: That does not seem unreasonable to me, the institution is funding your department and your department is paying you a salary for your work on their clock (for the department's client). Of course, this should have been clarified in advance in a contract involving the department…

Comment: That's why the grant proposal committee should have given you a *honorarium* instead of a *salary*...

Comment: I'll be honest, I am surprised about the general tone of answers here. Is this legal? Maybe. Is this common or ethical? Certainly not. I would take any request to pay back a honorarium as a clear-cut sign that this is a toxic place to work and you should get out.

Comment: @xLeitix that depends on the circumstances. If you are from a country where the universities are only paying partial wages and they expect you to work on the side (in the summer) to make ends meet, then it makes sense that you should not pay back an honorarium. But other countries do explicitly pay living wages, with the intend to enable the employees to focus on that one job. That is really nice for the employee, but it also means the employer has now a legitimate interest in ensuring that he gets what he pays for. The Netherlands is such a country.

Comment: @MaartenBuis I am a research manager in another such country (Sweden), and I find the notion outrageous. Let me put it like this - if a professor comes to you as a department head and says "I examined 3 doctoral dissertations for other unis this year and reviewed 10 grant proposals", do you then reduce their teaching or service load to make up for this additional effort? If you don't, you have zero leg to stand on to ask for any compensation they received for this external work. If you do, fair enough (but I don't believe you).

Comment: @xLeitix usually a lot is possible when it comes to compensation, but only if you discuss this *before* you actually accept or do the work. I think that that is the main problem the OP faces.

Comment: I realize this is not helpful, but in France for instance you need a written agreement from your university before you can do any additional paid work. It makes sense to ask before and not after

Comment: I live in the UK and I have never heard for a university to ask for these kind of monies to be paid back, if only to avoid a collective "work to rule" event.

Comment: Doing payed work for a third party during your payed vacation days is something most employers would frown upon.

Comment: @karl but that is the option they give me!

Answer (score 24):

Since you are in the Netherlands, your employment is most likely subject to the Collective Labour Agreement for Dutch Universities. [The latest copy I could find can be found here](https://www.universiteitenvannederland.nl/files/documenten/CAO/2022/UNL-18575-07-CAO%20Nederlandse%20Universiteiten%202022%20%28EN%29%20(2).pdf). I am not a lawyer and this is not legal advice, but Article 1.14 and 1.15 are potentially relevant. These basically say that you need prior permission for certain ancillary activities, and that you can only accept reimbursements with permission from your employer. Whether serving on a grant panel is an ancillary activity or not is another question, but it seems that the article about reimbursements applies regardless.

Comment: Note that article 1.15 only applies for activities in capacity as an employee of the university ( “ in function” in the Dutch version of the test). So it becomes relevant if your function as an employee of the university is relevant to you serving on a grant panel.

Comment: @TimRias - well, asking a physics professor to review physics grant proposals seems to be fully in line with their physics position at the university?

Comment: Thanks! I would be highly surprised if serving on a grant panel constitutes an ancillary activity (i.e., activity _not_ related to my academic work or employment). Moreover, it seems that I need to inform my employer and gain permission for ancillary activities, but serving in a panel (or any other reviewing activity) requires absolutely no permission from my employer, it is part of my academic life.

Comment: Ancillary activities are defined in 1.14.1 as " any work he performs for third parties", so it probably does count as  ancillary activities.

Comment: @MaartenBuis If that was the case, then according to the above, I would need to inform my line manager any time I read or review a paper. There is a line to be drawn on what constitutes reasonable academic activity.

Comment: @PsySp as I told you before: You do not need to convince me, you need to convince your line manager. In all likelihood (s)he will tell you to report all paid work. But you need to talk to her or him, not to us. Whatever we say will not affect you. Whatever your line manager says will affect you.

Comment: @MaartenBuis Fair enough, but that applies to virtually every case. I simply ask if this is a "normal" demand and, if not, how to potentially handle it besides the "do whatever they tell you".

Comment: @PsySp I don't see "work" defined clearly in the linked document, but it seems reasonable to me that "work" would practically mean "work for pay", as anything else you do without being paid is not work. So, reading and reviewing papers seem like reasonable academic activities under your ordinary job, but if someone is paying you extra that is implying you're doing some additional work not covered by the pay of your ordinary job.

Comment: @BryanKrause Got it. Reviewing papers, is free and not ancillary. Reviewing grant proposals is payed, but I need to give them back the entire compensation from a national funding body. Makes total sense to me!

Comment: @PsySp since it is in the CAO it is standard. I did not tell you that your only option is "do whatever they tell you". I also mentioned that your other option is to "fight", but you would need a lawyer for that. In the Netherlands, if you are a member of a trade-union, then they will also provide legal assistence in such cases. However, your chance of winning a fight is not helped by the fact that you did not discuss the pay before starting the work.

Comment: I don't think grant reviewing panels count as ancillary activities. This is academic service, the only difference being that in some cases you are paid for prepping for and being present at the meetings.

Comment: @PsySp If you think that it is a regular part of your university job, then you can't take an extra salary for it. I think that's not unreasonable. You can't have it both ways: Either it's part of your job and in that case you're paid by your university, or it's not part of your job and in that case the agency that contracts for your work needs to pay you. But you can't claim it's part of your regular job *and* draw a second salary for it -- that's double dipping, and that's the part your employer is upset about.

Comment: It is official: this is _not_ considered ancillary activity. From U. Twente "_Activities such as participation in a scientific committee or consultative body, editorial work and reviewing articles are generally not considered ancillary activities. Neither are lectures and other ad hoc work you do in the context of your employment with the UT for third parties. It is sufficient to make working agreements with your supervisor in writing regarding these activities._"

Comment: And here is the link: https://www.utwente.nl/en/service-portal/employment-personal-development/terms-of-employment/ancillary-activities-nevenwerkzaamheden#:~:text=The%20definition%20of%20ancillary%20activities,your%20job%20at%20the%20University.

Comment: @PsySp: Note the word "generally" in your quote: it means there can be exceptions, and I wouldn't be surprised if getting paid for participating in a committee is considered an exception. (Also, did you actually "make working agreements with your supervisor in writing" regarding this?) In any case, even if this is not considered an ancillary activity, article 1.15 of the collective agreement linked in the answer (which says that "*In his capacity, the employee is not allowed to accept reimbursements, remuneration or gifts, unless the employer grants its permission.*") presumably still applies.

Answer (score 18):

There are often rules that govern how much you can work "on the side". It makes sense that you cannot do additional paid work during the hours that you are already employed. So at a minimum there are usually rules that ensure you are "on your own time" when doing additional work. So what you describe does not sound weird to me. Whether there is anything you can do about it is something you need to discuss with a legal expert. Whether that is worth it is something you need to decide.

Comment: Thank you. However, it still does not make sense to me for the following reasons: there is no such clause on my contract/agreement and there is no such written relevant rule afaik. Second, this is academic work, pretty much like reviewing a paper and, again afaik, every kind of academic work is included on my contract. It is not a freelance work like private lessons or working on a youtube channel.

Comment: The department wants OP to be a member of a scientific community, and that includes being on a panel. The department already paid for you activities and would not like the OP to double-dip. But OP might want to deduct any additional costs from the compensation package before reimbursement.

Comment: @ThomasSchwarz Why double dip? Then why the funding body offers a compensation? They can directly pay to the department and avoid the misleading part about personal compensation.

Comment: I am not your department head. It does not matter if you convince me or not. What matters is that your department head thinks that (s)he has the right, or even duty, to ask that money back. The right way of responding to that is something you need to discuss with a lawyer, if you want the confrontation. Alternatively, you can just pay up and be extra careful next time "paid" opportunities arise.

Comment: @PsySp Not sure how it works where you are, but in the US it's common that faculty are responsible for finding money for some fraction of their time, usually through grants. There may be options to make up shortfalls with extra teaching, or you might just need to go with less pay. So, taking up an assignment like this covers part of that salary you need to cover. But, if the institution is already paying you to do something with that time, they're not going to be happy if do something else to get paid again.

Comment: In the US, most faculty is on a 9 months contract (but with the annual pay stretched over 12 months). Sometimes their contract allows them one day a week of for paid activities related to their scholarship, such as consulting or working for a company.

Comment: @PsySp They don't know your department, they know you.

Comment: @user253751 What? Of course they know my department, it is a national funding body and they want a diverse (from multiple institutions) panel.

Comment: @PsySP They don't know your contractual obligations to your department. They want you to serve on a panel, so they ask you. If that somehow conflicts with your contractual obligations, then that is for you to sort out. Or at the least, for you to inform them of and ask to handle.

Comment: @Servaes everybody working on a Dutch university has a contract that falls under the Collective Labor Agreement. So, they do know my contractual obligations (the individual differences do not matter in this particular situation)

Comment: @PsySP That still doesn't make it their problem. You have entered a contract with your employer. It is on you and your employer to uphold it. Not any third party.

Comment: Of course it is a rather messy situation that is unsatisfactory for both you and your employer. The correct course of action would have been to inform your employer *before* accepting the invitation, as your contract (or CAO) explicitly states you should do. Then your employer can decide whether you can do this during your regular working hours, or whether you should take vacation days or unpaid leave to do this paid work for a third party.

Comment: @Servaes Agreed. It is just it could never cross my mind that they would ask the compensation back. Now that's a great incentive to _never_ again do such an activity in the future.

Comment: @PsySp the resolution could also be to do such activity but inform them of this potential issue.

Comment: @PsySp or just discuss any work with compensation you may receive with your department *before* accepting that work. Often there are ways to let you keep some or all of that or compensate you in some other way (maybe not a reduction in teaching load, but assigning courses that are easier or less work to teach, or putting you in committees that are less work, or increasing your travel fund, or ...). But such a discussion is only possible *before* you accept that work.

Answer (score 11):

It seems perfectly reasonable to me. Your employer pays you for certain hours. They own those hours. Most institutions are happy for you to use some of their time for academic services that don't directly benefit them, but of course if there is any extra compensation for that time then it belongs to the owner of the time, i.e. your employer. In most cases (reviewing a paper, etc) this is zero, and your employer doesn't particularly need you to tell them every time "I have reviewed a paper, and here is the zero Euros I got paid". But the same principle applies - all the compensation belongs to them. In some cases they might decide to waive their right to it, but that is their decision to make.

I would just take them as holiday days. Then you are being compensated for time that belongs to you, so you get to keep the money. (Of course, this assumes that the compensation is enough to make it worthwhile.)

Comment: That would actually be perfectly reasonable if I was working only these hours my employer is paying me. But more often than not, I work easily work 60h/w without getting payed back the extra time and effort I put. So, according to them, they do not own me a dime for any extra hour of work I put for them, but I own them all the compensation I get for working in a grant panel.

Comment: @PsySp: …and you _might_ have leverage there; Google "work to rule". Maybe you could apologize for misunderstanding the amount of flexibility allowed and expected in your employment with the university, and say that in the future you will work on tracking your time more accurately to ensure that you'll neither spend any paid work time on personal activities (like this grant committee) nor accidentally work more than your agreed upon hours per week. Having a lawyer or a union rep with you might be a good idea — they'll know both what to say and how to say it without sounding whiny or petulant.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Knowing the Dutch system PsySp is probably on a temporary contract. What are the chances of getting that contract extended after such an action? After you worked like that for a while what will your publication record look like? So that leverage is pretty limited. If I were a department head in such a conversation I would strongly recommend you against such actions because I don't want you to hurt yourself, but if you insist I would not care one way or another. So that is how much leverage you have.

Comment: Work to rule can be powerful if done as a collective action. But it is still costly: everybodies publication record suffers, and they are competing on an international market even if they choose to stay in the Netherlands. If you want to go that route your best bet is probably to organize that through the unions.

Comment: @MaartenBuis: Agreed. However, the OP is also working a lot of unpaid overtime, which they're neither expected nor allowed to do under the [collective agreement](https://www.universiteitenvannederland.nl/files/documenten/CAO/2022/UNL-18575-07-CAO%20Nederlandse%20Universiteiten%202022%20%28EN%29%20(2).pdf). However, they _are_ (article 5.6, paragraph 3) allowed to agree with their employer to work extra hours on some days in exchange for time off on other days. So they could propose just that: take the days off and work extra hours (which they would do anyway) on other days to make up for it.

Comment: …of course they *should've* arranged that in advance, but presumably there's still something that may be arranged, if the university is willing to be flexible. And if they're _not_ willing to be flexible, then the OP *may* wish to politely hint that they don't need to be as flexible regarding their working hours as they've apparently been in the past, either.

Comment: Whenever you make a statement like that, you need to consider what you are going to do if the department head calls your bluff. Is the department head really going to notice if you don't spent the extra time on finishing paper xyz? Probably only when it is time to decide whether to continue to employ you...

Comment: @PsySp As an employer, they don't owe you extra hours they haven't **formally** asked you to perform. Your contract must be clear about this. If you, in the other hand, volunteered to give your employer roughly 50% more in number of hours from your time, remember that it's a personal choice. For you, it is extra labour that is providing some experience at best, detrimental to your life balance at worse. As for your employer, the truth is, most likely, they don't even care.

Answer (score 4):

Very surprised by this situation happening in the Netherlands and equally surprised by all the answers so far.

Compensation for interview panels is often ridiculously difficult to actually get transferred to your university account when you want to (which is the better solution IMHO since otherwise most of the $$$ goes to taxes). So in that respect, I'm all in favor. Just make sure to get it transferred to/added to your lab account so you are the one in control of spending it.

Knowing the system, I assume we're talking about a couple hundred euros at most. Nice to have as unrestricted funds for your lab, but not substantial for your university's budget. So don't add it to the pile.

As for work done during hours: Aren't most of us doing this on evenings and weekends??? I think it is really weird that there is talk of this work being done "on the clock". Does that mean you should never work more than stated in your contract? Good luck with that in academia...

Comment: I did most of this panel preparation work during my free evenings. Also, the money will be transferred to the department itself, I will have no clue/access that these funds (about 700eu)

Comment: Hmm, you're talking about funds being transferred to a university/lab account - something that would be used for research expenses maybe? Whereas, it seems OP got the funds personally. If the former is typical, and the latter is unusual, could that explain the confusion here? That is, OP thought this was money they could spend on themselves, and the assumption for the grant org and university is that these funds are spent on research expenses, and that's why the institution wants the money?

Comment: *Also, the money will be transferred to the department itself,* That is new information. That suggests that it was never intended for you personally, but more for your lab account/travel account/some other account that you can use for "nice" things at work like going to a conference or stocking up a contract for a student assistent. This means that you need to know how university accounting works, and that is an arcane art in itself. Here I cannot overemphasize the importance of friendly relations with the secretaries.

Answer (score -3):

Engage work to rule, aka malicious compliance.

If you're paid to work 37 hours (insert your actual time here) per week, then actually work that.

Then apply for leave for the time you're doing grant panel things, and all is good and above board.

You're fulfilling your contractual obligations.

Comment: All of that is strictly speaking true, but what will happen when you ask for your contract to be extended?

Comment: And therein lies the issue with the casualisation of academia.

Comment: sure, we can agree that that many temporary contracts is bad. However, it still means that if the OP follows your advise (s)he will *not* attain her goals, but *will* suffer harm in her/his/their career. That is why I think this is bad advise. Is that how the world should be? No. Is that how the world is? Yes.